# Read an file in two hashes inorder to retain the order

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to read a file with user information categorized under a location, I want to fill in the some of the fields using user input and output the file while keeping the fields under each location intact for eg - file

```
[California] 
$;FIrst_Name = 
$;Last_Name=
$;Age =

[NewYork]
$;FIrst_Name = 
$;Last_Name=
$;Age =

[Washington]
$;FIrst_Name = 
$;Last_Name=
$;Age =
```

Once user provides input from command line it should look it

```
[California] 
$;FIrst_Name = Jack
$;Last_Name= Daner
$;Age = 27

[NewYork]
$;FIrst_Name = Jill
$;Last_Name= XYZ
$;Age = 30

[Washington]
$;FIrst_Name = Kim
$;Last_Name= ABC
$;Age = 25
```

The order of First_Name, Last_Name and Age within each location can change and even order of locations can change, but each location section should remain separate and intact. I wrote following code so far and some of my code works for taking whole file in one hash, but i am not able to preserve each location section within it! I tried using two hashes - can someone please help me as it is getting really complex for me! Thanks a lot. ( I had another issue with a similar file as well, but unfortunately could not resolve it either)

EDITED code

```
Open the file 


use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

    sub read_config {
my $phCmdLineOption = shift;
my $phConfig        = shift;
my $sInputfile      = shift;
open($input.file, "<$InputFile") or die "Error! Cannot open $InputFile
    + for reading: $!";

            while (<$input.file>) {
                    $_ =~ s/\s+$//;
                    next if ($_ =~ /^#/);
                    next if ($_ =~ /^$/);

                if ($_ =~ m/^\[(\S+)\]$/) {
                $sComponent = $1;
                    next;
                }
                elsif ($_ =~ m/^;;\s*(.*)/) {
                    $sDesc .= "$1.";
                    next;
                }
                elsif ($_ =~ m/\$;(\S+)\$;\s*=\s*(.*)/) {
                    $sParam = $1;


     $sValue = $2;

if ((defined $sValue) && ($sValue !~ m/^\s*$/)) {
                $phfield->{$sCategory}{$sParam} = ["$sValue", "$sDesc"];
            }
            else {
                $field->{$sCategory}{$sParam} = [undef, "$sDesc"];
            }
                        }

                        $sParam = $sValue = $sDesc = "";
                        next;
                    }
                }
```

Write the new file -

```
sub write_config {

my $phCmdLineOption = shift;
    my $phConfig        = shift;
    my $sOut        = shift;
open(outfile, ">$sOut") or die " $!";

        foreach $sCategory (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %{$fields}) {
                print $outfile "[$sCategory]\n";
                foreach $sParam (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %{$fields-{$sCategory}}) {
                        $sDesc = ((defined $phConfig->{$sCategory}{$sParam}[1]) $fields->{$sCategory}{$sParam}[1] : "");
                        print $outfile ";;$sDesc\n" if ((defined $sDesc) && ($sDesc !~ m/^$/));

                        $sValue = ((defined $fields->{$sCategory}{$sParam}[0]) ? $fields->{$sCategory}{$sParam}[0] : undef);

                        print $outfile "$sValue" if (defined $sValue);
                        print $outfile "\n";
                }
                print $outfile "\n";
        }

        close($outfile);

    return;
```

Note -  I have posted this question on PerlMonks forum as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no hash creation in this code.

Comment: @AnkP: You can ask your question wherever you want, but it's only polite to say in each case where else you have posted it, otherwise you may well have people working on a solution for you when you already have a working answer

Comment: But you don't create the hash referred to by `$fields` anywhere. You just mess with `$sParam`, `$sValue` and `$sDesc` for a bit and then write code that uses the contents of `%$fields`.  Your question is very confusing

Comment: @bart - Sorry I missed adding the write out part of code, I have updated my post. thanks!

Comment: @AnkP: You still don't populate the hash. And what is `$input.file`? I'm pretty certain it doesn't do what you think it does. And I think you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place at the top of your program, which is *essential*

Comment: @Borodin, thanks for looking at my code, I have made several edits, sorry my code has gone really messy, I tried to break down the code in two subroutines, one for reading in the file and one out writing out. I will clean up my code further, any suggestions will be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User input here need be organized, and for this we can use named options for each field, plus one for state.  The [Getopt option](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash) for reading into a hash is useful here. We also need to associate names of these options with field names. With that in hand it is simple to process the file since we have a ready mechanism to identify lines of interest.

By putting lines on a ref-array we can keep the order as well, and that refarray is a value for the section-key in the hash.  The hash is not necessary but adds flexibility for future development. Once we are at it we can also keep the order of sections by using a simple auxiliary array.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use feature qw(say);

# Translate between user input and field name ($;) in file
my ($o1, $o2, $o3) = qw(first last age);
my @tags = ('FIrst_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Age');
my %desc = ($tags[0] => $o1, $tags[1] => $o2, $tags[2] => $o3);
my (%input, $state);
GetOptions(\%input, "$o1=s", "$o2=s", "$o3=i", 'state=s' => \$state);

my $locinfo = 'loc_info.txt';
open my $in_fh, '<', $locinfo;

my (%conf, @sec_order, $section, $field);
while (my $line = <$in_fh>)
{
    chomp($line);
    next if $line =~ m/^\s*$/;
    # New section ([]), for hash and order-array
    if ($line =~ m/^\s*\[(.*)\]/) {
        push @sec_order, $section = $1;
        next;
    }

    # If we are in a wrong state just copy the line
    if ($section ne $state) {
        push @{$conf{$section}}, $line . "\n";
        next;
    }

    if (($field) = $line =~ m/^\$;\s*(.*?)\s*=/ ) {
        if (exists $input{$desc{$field}}) {
            # Overwrite what is there or append
            $line =~ s|^\s*(.*?=\s*)(.*)|$1 $input{$desc{$field}}|;
        }
    }
    else { warn "Unexpected line: |$line|  --" }

    push @{$conf{$section}}, $line . "\n";
}
close $in_fh;

for (@sec_order) { say "[$_]";  say @{$conf{$_}}; }
```

Invocation

```
script.pl -state STATE -first FIRST_NAME -last LAST_NAME -age INT
```

Any option may be left out in which case that field is not touched.  A field supplied on the command line will be overwritten if it has something.  (This can be changed easily.)  This works for a single-state entry as it stands but which is simple to modify if needed.

This is a basic solution.  The first next thing would be to read the field names from the file itself, instead of having them hard-coded.  (This would avoid the need to spot the typo `FIrst` and inconsistent spacings before `=`, for one thing.)  But the more refinements are added, the more one is getting into template development. At some point soon it will be a good idea to use a module.

*Note*  The regex delimiter above is different than elsewhere (`|`) to avoid the editor coloring all red.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting lost in the detail and skipping over some basics which is unnecessarily complicating the problem.  Those basics are;

1. Indent your code properly (it's amazing the difference this makes)
2. Always use the **/x** modifier on regex and lots of whitespace to increase readability
3. When using lots of regexs, use "quote rule", **qr**, to seperate regex definition from regex use

Apart from that, you were headed in the right direction but there are a couple of insights on the algorithm you were missing which further increased the complexity.

Firstly, for small-time parsing of data, look out for the possibility that matching one type of line immediately disqualifies matching of other types of line.  All the `elsif`'s aren't necessary since a line that matches a category is never going to match a LastName or Age and vice versa.

Secondly, when you get a match, see if you can do what's needed immediately rather than storing the result of the match for processing later.  In this case, instead of saving a *"component"* or *"category"* in a variable, put it immediately into the hash you're building.

Thirdly, if you're updating text files that are not huge, consider working on a new version of the file and then at the end of the program declare the current version old, and the new version current.  This reduces the chances of unintentionally modifying something in place and allows comparison of the update with the original after execution - if necessary, "rollback" of the change in trivially easy which one of your users may be very grateful for one day.

Fourthly and most of all, you've only got a couple of attributes or components to worry about, so deal with them in the concrete rather than the abstract.  You can see below that I've looped over `qw( First_Name Last_Name Age)` rather than all keys of the hash.  Now obviously, if you have to deal with open-ended or unknown attributes you can't do it this way but in this case, AFAICT, your fields are fixed.

Here's a version that basically works given the above mentioned constraints.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.12 ;
use Getopt::Long ;

my %db ;                 # DB hash
my $dbf = "data.txt" ;   # DB file name
my $dbu = "data.new" ;   # updated DB file name
my $dbo = "data.old" ;   # Old DB file name

my  ($cat, $first, $last, $age)    ;    # Default is undef
GetOptions( 'cat=s'   =>  \$cat    ,
            'first=s' =>  \$first  ,
            'last=s'  =>  \$last   ,
            'age=i'   =>  \$age
          );

die "Category option (--cat=...) is compolsory\n" unless $cat ;

open my $dbh, '<', $dbf or die "$dbf: $!\n";    # DB Handle
open my $uph, '>', $dbu or die "$dbu: $!\n";    # UPdate Handle

# REs for blank line, category header and attribute specification
my $blank_re = qr/ ^ \s* $ /x ;
my $cat_re   = qr/ ^  \[ (\w+) \] \s* $ /x ;
my $attr_re  = qr/ ^ \$ ; (?<key>\w+) \s* = \s* (?<val>\N*) $ /x ;

while ( <$dbh> ) {
    next unless /$cat_re/ ;
    my %obj = ( cat => $1 ) ;
    while ( <$dbh> )  {
        $obj{ $+{key} } = $+{val} if  /$attr_re/ ;
        last if /$blank_re/
    }
    $db{ $obj{cat} }  = \%obj
}

# Grab existing obj, otherwise presume we're adding a new one
my $obref = $db{ $cat } //  { cat => $cat } ;
$obref->{ First_Name }  =   $first if defined $first ;
$obref->{ Last_Name }   =   $last  if defined $last  ;
$obref->{ Age }         =   $age   if defined $age   ;

# Update the DB with the modified/new one
$db{ $obref->{cat} }  =  $obref ;

for (sort keys %db) {
    my $obref = $db{ $_ } ;
    printf $uph "[%s]\n", $obref->{ cat } ;
    for (qw(  First_Name Last_Name Age  ))  {
        printf $uph '$;' . "%s = %s\n",  $_, $obref->{ $_ }
    }
    print $uph "\n"
}

close $dbh ;
close $dbu ;
rename $dbf , $dbo ;
rename $dbu , $dbf ;
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions @Marty! your code looks much clear, my files are short, so adding into new hash will be better. Just one question on pattern match (which I am still learning) - I am getting this error - `Missing braces on \N{} at test.pl line 25, within pattern
Sequence (?<k...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/ ^ \$ ; (?<k <-- HERE ey>\w+) \s* = \s* (?<val>*) $ / at config.pl line 25` which is `my $attr_re  = qr/ ^ \$ ; (?<key>\w+) \s* = \s* (?<val>\N*) $ /x ;` should I get rid of "?" ? thanks again!

Comment: That line uses "named capture variables."  It works at my end.  Try replacing that line with this `my $attr_re  = qr/ ^ \$ ; (\w+) \s* = \s* (.*) $ /x ;` and line 31 has to change to this: `$obj{ $1 } = $2 if  /$attr_re/ ;`

Comment: Marty, Thanks a lot, but I am still not abel to run it, do I need to use some specific module? I am getting error `Search pattern not terminated at test.pl line 41.` for line `my $obref = $db{ $cat } //  { cat => $cat } ;`. Can you please share how you execute this? Thanks again!

Comment: It might be the use of the defined-or operator, `//`, which came out in v5.10.  Try replacing that line with: `my $obref = defined $db{ $cat }  ?   $db{ $cat }  :  { cat => $cat } ;`

Comment: Thanks marty for the prompt response, my script works now but if I give values for only component/category, like - `perl config4.pl --cat California --first Ana --last kov --age 27` the output looks like `[]
$;First_Name =
$;Last_Name =
$;Age =

[California]
$;First_Name = Ana
$;Last_Name = kov
$;Age = 27` It does not print out retain rest of the components in the input file

Comment: What you are seeing there is a "blank" entry followed by a correct entry - possibly due the input file being empty.  I didn't test the script with an empty input file - could you edit the db file, leave one or more correct entries in it and the try it again?

Comment: thanks a lot Marty, I used the sample file I posted above in the question as input file, not an empty file..I just did not give input for any other category except California in the command line. The code does populate the values for [California] but does not retain rest of the categories in the input file, instead of that it outputs a blank entry

Comment: What that means is that it's not recognizing any of the existing data.  The reason why you see values for California is because it fails to read in anything and then proceeds to add a new California.  Line 28, `next unless /$cat_re/ ;` means "go back and read the next line if this doesn't match" so, it will tear through the whole file reading in nothing if the `$cat_re` doesn't match.  That's my guess on what's happening.  Are there any spaces around the square brackets in the data file?  Try moving the RE into the statement directly - ie: `next unless /  \[  \s* (\w+)  \s* \]  \s*  /x`

Comment: Marty, I made the edits, can you please explain just one thing - how will user input multiple category names in one command using Getoptions? Thanks!

Comment: That's great news!  Re, multiple categories - you can't do it with this script.  If you specified `--cat=California --first=Ted --cat=NewYork --last=Smith`, there is now way for the script to tell if "Smith" belongs to NewYork or California.  Same with "Ted".  You could make a script that would do that but it would be much bigger.  Instead, simply do two runs; perl config4.pl --cat California --first Ana --last kov --age 27   and then after that config4.pl --cat NewYork --first Terry --last Smith --age 34.  Finally, if this has been useful, please consider ticking the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marty, yes your solution resolved my problem!

Comment: Would you then please consider ticking the answer?